# WPF: Using an image converted to vector graphics in a XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, vector-graphics

I converted `image.png` to `image.svg` using Vector Magic and then to image.xaml using svg2xaml, which according to [this](http://blog.fossmo.net/post/Converting-from-SVG-to-XAML.aspx) is supposed to work with Visual Studio.

After adding image.xaml to the project and setting its build path to resource, I add the following line to my XAML file:

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource image}" />
```

According to the tutorial [here](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=d849072b-4e45-4ad4-b28c-71341ea30d46). But, I'm getting a `"Error    1   StaticResource reference 'image' was not found."` error.

On [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907315.aspx) MSDN page, it shows that not adding a previous "declaration" results in an error, but if I already linked the resource in the project, isn't that already taken care of? I also don't know what type the "declaration" would need to include, assuming I need one.

Otherwise, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply marking image.xaml with a build action of "Resource" does not make it a `ResourceDictionary` or allow it to be referenced inside any XAML file inside of your project.  For your above code to work you'll need to:

1. Have a `ResourceDictionary` file which contains your image in XAML format.  The key inside of your resource inside that dictionary needs to be **image**.  For a blank `ResourceDictionary` to insert your generated XAML, right-click on your project, and select **Add-->Resource Dictionary...**
2. Include a reference to your `ResourceDictionary` inside of your App/Window/container via the `ResourceDictionary/MergedDictionary` mechanism described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries.aspx).

After this, you should be able to use the above `StaticResource` markup extension in your `ContentControl`.